Contextual filters with taxonomy
I have built a normal view with a contextual filter on a taxonomy term:

This taxonomy term consists of 6 terms, with four terms the call of the view works without problems and with two terms I get the following error message:
TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string - int in __TwigTemplate_f8f1a2c97d1bdf992eb6d482520f02b8->doDisplay() (line 54 of /srv/www/stage-multisite/home/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(360) : eval()'d code).

What could be the problem?
Thank you and best regards
Bavra
      uuid: 80d91b4f-14a1-4f5d-b9b6-c22e4e050dc7
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.taxonomy_term.field_sector_image
    - image.style.og_image
    - taxonomy.vocabulary.sector
  module:
    - image
    - taxonomy
    - user
id: seed_meet_enterprises
label: 'Seed Meet Enterprises'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: taxonomy_term_field_data
base_field: tid
display:
  default:
    id: default
    display_title: Default
    display_plugin: default
    position: 0
    display_options:
      title: 'Seed Meet Enterprises'
      fields:
        view_taxonomy_term:
          id: view_taxonomy_term
          table: taxonomy_term_data
          field: view_taxonomy_term
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          plugin_id: entity_link
          label: ''
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          text: ''
          output_url_as_text: true
          absolute: false
        name:
          id: name
          table: taxonomy_term_field_data
          field: name
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          entity_field: name
          plugin_id: term_name
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: true
            path: 'enterprise-profiles{{ view_taxonomy_term }}'
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: true
            path_case: lower
            trim_whitespace: true
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: false
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          convert_spaces: true
        field_sector_image:
          id: field_sector_image
          table: taxonomy_term__field_sector_image
          field: field_sector_image
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: true
            path: 'enterprise-profiles{{ view_taxonomy_term }}'
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: true
            path_case: lower
            trim_whitespace: true
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: image
          settings:
            image_link: ''
            image_style: og_image
            image_loading:
              attribute: lazy
          group_column: ''
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          offset: 0
          items_per_page: 10
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: none
        options: {  }
      empty: {  }
      sorts:
        name:
          id: name
          table: taxonomy_term_field_data
          field: name
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          entity_field: name
          plugin_id: standard
          order: ASC
          expose:
            label: ''
            field_identifier: ''
          exposed: false
      arguments: {  }
      filters:
        status:
          id: status
          table: taxonomy_term_field_data
          field: status
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          entity_field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          value: '1'
          group: 1
          expose:
            operator: ''
        vid:
          id: vid
          table: taxonomy_term_field_data
          field: vid
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          entity_field: vid
          plugin_id: bundle
          value:
            sector: sector
      style:
        type: grid_responsive
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          columns: 2
          cell_min_width: 100
          grid_gutter: 10
          alignment: horizontal
      row:
        type: fields
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          query_comment: ''
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_tags: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      css_class: 'max-w-screen-md  mx-auto px-4 box-content'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - user.permissions
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.taxonomy_term.field_sector_image'
  page_1:
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    display_plugin: page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: enterprises
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - user.permissions
      tags:
        - 'config:field.sto

rage.taxonomy_term.field_sector_image'

Have you got a custom twig template used in this view? Sounds like something in there might be causing the error
